# Why asking me for a token when installing laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, lamp

My laptop has 3 php versions 7.2, 7.4 and 8.1
when installing a brand new laravel i got asked about a token even it's not installing a private repo

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that `auth.json` file is corrupted, So i deleted it as no need for it now.

it is located in `$HOME/.config/composer/`

Comment: this is the only answer to this issue I've come across after hours of searching

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solutions is you may remove/uninstall the composer and tick mark with all of its contents and then install again the composer.

It will just remove your global laravel/installer.

Hope it will work for you.